Is there more to the flag counter than just grabbing all the flags?
In New Super Mario Bros. U + New Super Luigi U, I have a Luigi saved data that has a golden 94 on it that indicates I 100% beat the game:

But in my Mario saved data, I have all but one flag. I scanned both save file’s maps (including the Ghost forest and Star Coin world) and I have all the secret paths and courses completed:

So my question is, are there anything else that are included in the flag count? Like Toad Houses, make friends with all Baby Yoshis, stuff like that?

Your Mario save data shows only four stars as opposed to five. And since you only reached 93 flag poles it does seem like you are missing a level clear - i.e. you have not been to every level.
To get the last star on the save file you got to reach all level flagpoles (82 normal and 12 secret exists), get all star coins and catch Nabbit in worlds 1 through 7. Things like Toad houses or Baby Yoshis are irrelevant.
Consider hitting pause in-game, going to the star coin totals menu and go through all worlds. If the number in the corner is highlighted in a yellow rectangle you have found all coins and thus all levels:

If this is not the case you are probably also missing a level.
The levels that contain secret exists are...

 1-2, 2-4, 3-Ghost, 4-Ghost, 5-2, 5-Ghost, 5-4, 5-5, 6-5, 6-Tower, 7-Ghost and 8-1

Another thing to consider is World 5, the Soda Jungle. The levels Painted Swampland (4) and Deepsea Ruins (5) contain two exists of which the secret exit is required but the regular exit loops you back to the previous level. You may be missing a path there.
Finally if you have completed a level as Nabbit it will show up as purple on the world map and not count towards completed levels. Perhaps a level slipped in?


I have all the Star Coins in all worlds, so I definitely have completed every level in the game. Would capturing Nabbit in all worlds count as the last flag and final star in the game?

No, catching Nabbit everywhere will not grant you a flag. I think I have an idea what you are missing though.
World 5 (Soda Jungle) is a mess since two levels contain a regular and a secret exit. The secret exit is what lets you continue onwards, the other will cause you to loop back. You have have found the secret exit in one level but not the regular exit leaving you short of a flagpole.
Double-check Painted Swampland (4) and Deepsea Ruins (5) and see if you are missing paths leading out there.

I have both the way out of the forest (including the secret exit after the ghost house) and the looping bridge that leads back to the same levels. I do see the confusion in Soda Jungle, but I made good observations in every world before I asked.

The best advice I could give it to verify all levels with secrets exits and play them again - both regular and secret flag poles. The 12 levels are 1-2, 2-4, 3-Ghost, 4-Ghost, 5-2, 5-4, 5-5, 6-Tower, 6-5, 7-Ghost and 8-1. Additionally apparently a level does not count as cleared if you beat it as Nabbit (the level on the map will be purple, not blue).

Interesting, I didn’t know about the purple level thing. I’ll try those and see if I may have missed anything. Thanks.

5-Ghost, just to add to your list

I grabbed all the flags from the levels you mentioned, and some how I still have one flag missing. ☹️ I’m going to do a DEEP dive into why this is happening.

Could I have possibly discovered a bug? I don’t know. I might just play all the courses once more just in case I managed (or the game managed) to miss one.

In the meantime I booted my copy of the game and checked routes as well. I know you said you checked the levels already but consider double-checking 5-2 (Bridge over Poisoned Waters) and 6-5 (Walking Piranha Plants) because these two levels also have regular and secret exits that cause a loop. A missing path might have slipped in there?

Yep, got the brick bridge and the track path that leads to the red switch. I think I am going to edit my question to include a little video of my paths so you can check it out.

Well, unless I can do that. I’m not sure how to add a video to my post on an iPhone.

You can only post videos via Youtube links. You could upload the video (unlisted if you wish to do so) to a private account and post the link in the question or a comment.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
